# file input stream need to read from the Object

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, fileinputstream

I am trying to save data onDestroy method inside a bottomsheetDialogFragment. I am saving information on destroy method and getting saved info onCreate method.

but I am getting an error on this particular line

```
listOfItem= new ArrayList<> (Arrays.asList ( split ) );
```

I am adding list using recylerView from Item class but I don't know how to add split string into the ArrayList.

hope you understand my question. below is my code thanks very much

```
public class CustomFragment_1 extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private CustomAdapter_1 mAdapter;
ArrayList<Item> listOfItem;


String cName;
Button btn;
FlatDialog flatDialog;
EditText editText;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate ( R.layout.fragment_custom_1, container, false );


    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById ( R.id.customRV );
    btn = (Button) view.findViewById ( R.id.button1 );
    editText = (EditText) view.findViewById ( R.id.edt1 );


    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager ( getContext () );
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager ( linearLayoutManager );

    listOfItem = new ArrayList<> ();

    mAdapter = new CustomAdapter_1 ( getContext (), listOfItem );
    recyclerView.setAdapter ( mAdapter );

    listOfItem.add ( new Item ( "FreeNow" ) );
    listOfItem.add ( new Item ( "Uber" ) );
    listOfItem.add ( new Item ( "Bolt" ) );


    btn.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            flatDialog = new FlatDialog ( getActivity () );
            flatDialog.setTitle ( "Company Name" )
                    .setSubtitle ( "Please add the name of the company" )
                    .setFirstTextFieldHint ( "Company Name" )
                    .setFirstButtonText ( "ADD" )
                    .setSecondButtonText ( "CANCEL" )
                    .withFirstButtonListner ( new View.OnClickListener () {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {

                            cName = flatDialog.getFirstTextField ();
                            listOfItem.add ( new Item ( cName ) );
                            mAdapter.notifyItemInserted ( listOfItem.size () );

                            flatDialog.dismiss ();

                        }
                    } )
                    .withSecondButtonListner ( new View.OnClickListener () {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            flatDialog.dismiss ();
                        }
                    } )
                    .show ();


        }

    } );

    loadContent ();
    return view;
}

public void loadContent() {
    File path = getActivity ().getFilesDir ();
    File readFrom = new File ( path, "list.txt" );
    byte[] content = new byte[(int) readFrom.length ()];

    FileInputStream stream = null;

    try {
        stream = new FileInputStream ( readFrom );
        stream.read ( content );

        String s = new String ( content );
        s = s.substring ( 1, s.length () - 1 );
        String split[] = s.split ( ", " );

        listOfItem = new ArrayList<> ( Arrays.asList ( split ) );

        mAdapter = new CustomAdapter_1 ( getContext (), listOfItem );
        recyclerView.setAdapter ( mAdapter );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace ();
    }


}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    File path = getContext ().getFilesDir ();
    try {
        FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream ( new File ( path, "list.txt" ) );
        writer.write ( listOfItem.toString ().getBytes () );
        writer.close ();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace ();
    }


    super.onDestroy ();
}
```

}

below is the error I am getting

```
error: incompatible types: cannot infer type arguments for ArrayList<>
        listOfItem = new ArrayList<> ( Arrays.asList ( split ) );
                                  ^
reason: inference variable E has incompatible bounds
  equality constraints: Item
  lower bounds: T,String
where E,T are type-variables:
E extends Object declared in class ArrayList
T extends Object declared in method <T>asList(T...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to side-step your actual error because there are multiple issues with your code, and then I'll suggest a better way to do it.

First of all, you should be aware that onDestroy() doesn't always get called (for example, when the app is force-closed).

Second, you're trying to perform IO on a UI thread, which is gonna cause your app to freeze both when reading and writing the data.

You would be much better of using something like [SharedPreferences](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shared-preferences-in-android-with-examples/) to store  your `listOfItem` array. And you'll want to save it to `SharedPreferences` any time that array changes, not just onDestroy(). That way it'll always be up to date, even when onDestroy() isn't called.

And finally, you'll be better off using an object serialization library, like [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson), if you insist on writing objects to file storage yourself. There's no reason to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thanks very much for your time let me try to use SharedPreferences thanks again

Comment: just of for my own knowledge I just want to know what I was doing wrong in the above code. I will use sharedPreference. but want to know what was I doing wrong on the above code  thanks

Comment: I think it's asking you for the data type of items in the array. Something like new ArrayList<String> ( Arrays.asList ( split ) );